# .NET MVC URL Routing Help

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvcroutehandler

I am trying to configure an ErrorController in my .NET MVC application, and I am unable to hit any actions on the controller currently, so I believe it may be because I need to register the URL route in the **global.asax**

The Error controller is the following:

```
public class ErrorController: Controller
{

    /*Default Redirect Error Page*/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    /*Generic Error Page*/
    public ActionResult Generic()
    {
        return View();
    }
    /*Status Code: 400*/
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to call the actions above by the following URL's respectively.

~/Error/
~/Error/Generic
~/Error/NotFound

I would believe that in the **Global.asax** file I would need to register these routes using something like the following:

```
routes.Add(new Route("error/{action}", new MvcRouteHandler())){controller = "Error", action = "";
```

How would I add/specify the correct route handler for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the default url provided in global.asax would work for your url but if you want a specific url then go for:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Error", // Route name
      "error/{action}", // URL without parameters
       new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
);
```

and if you want parameters:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Error", // Route name
      "error/{action}/{param}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", param = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
);
```